# Getting the error while trying to execute the Websphere Portal8.5 xml access scripts

Tags: websphere-portal

I am trying to execute the below script getting the below error

1. go to bin folder in to websphere portal 8.5 server
2. execute the below command:

   .xmlaccess.sh -user wps_admin_userid -password wps_admin_password -url http://example.com:pw /wps/config -in /file/export-of-pages-webapps.xml -out /file/export-of-pages-webapps-result.xml

While executing the above command and getting the below error

```
<message id="EJPXA0001E">EJPXA0001E: An error occurred while processing the XML configuration request.</message>
        <message>Message: Could not save object in repository., 
Cause: com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.repository.RepositoryException: Message: PrivilegedActionException caught, 
Cause: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: RT0002E: Error while calling a function createItems of PLS data manager (Message: Could not save object in repository.,
Cause: com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.repository.RepositoryException: Message: PrivilegedActionException caught, 
Cause: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: RT0002E: Error while calling a function createItems of PLS data manager)</message>
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the disk space in the DB server.  I have encountered the same issue few months ago and I resolved it by increasing the disk space in the DB server.

Also, you can check the permissions for the JCRDB.

Comment: Yes, I have increased the disk space, But still I am facing the same issue, can you please elaborate for JCR DB permissions , then I can try that option.

Comment: Do you see any exception on the DB logs db2diag.log ?  This will give you more details about the error.